# Flex application with access to local filesystem and network?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, web-applications, network-programming, filesystems

I'm developing kind of standalone kiosk and having trouble as in title.

Explanation:

- Application is launched in Google Chrome with **"--app=file://..."** option
- Application should play video files from local filesystem after user
  interaction and after playback is finished app will send log-message
  to web server.

Problem:

- When using with **"-use-network=false"** i can use local files and cannot
  send messages.
- When using with **"-use-network=true"** i can send messages but cannot
  red local files.
- When using with debugger and Safari on Mac locally - no problems.

Is there any way to get around this?
Software used: Debian, latest Google Chrome with latest pepper Flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in Adobe docs:

> The local-trusted sandbox—Local SWF files that are registered as
>   trusted (by users or by installer programs) are placed in the
>   local-trusted sandbox. System administrators and users also have the
>   ability to reassign (move) a local SWF file to or from the
>   local-trusted sandbox based on security considerations (see
>   Administrator controls and User controls). SWF files that are assigned
>   to the local-trusted sandbox can interact with any other SWF files and
>   can load data from anywhere (remote or local).

Besides that, I doubt there is an easy way to do both networking and access local files since this is how Flash security sandboxes work. Or you could write an AIR app (2.6 is last supported version on Linux) or wrap your swf in a native app that would act as a layer between .swf and network/filesystem interfaces.

Comment: Adding local folder with app to Trusted Location Settings and compiling app with **"-use-network=false"** solved the problem.
Thanks for reply!